# Python Tkinter socket.recv not receiving

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, connection, chat

I am trying to make a chat program with Python Tkinter, but my recv function *recvMSG()* either doesn't receive anything or just doesn't print anything.

Could you help me fix the receiving problem? Change the code anyway you want.

```
from Tkinter import *
import easygui
import socket
import threading
msgscount = 1

setup = False

def makeServer():
    global tcpclisock
    host = ''
    port = easygui.integerbox(msg='Enter a port...', title='Port', argUpperBound=100000)
    buffsize = 1024
    addr = (host, port)
    setup = True

    tcpsersock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsersock.bind(addr)
    tcpsersock.listen(5)
    tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accept()
    easygui.msgbox(msg=('Connected from: ', addr), title='Connected')

def connectServer():
    global tcpclisock
    setup = True
    host = easygui.choicebox(msg='Choose a host...', title='Choose Host', choices=('localhost'),buttons=('Select'))
port = easygui.integerbox(msg='Enter a port...', title='Port', argUpperBound=100000)
buffsize = 1024
addr = (host, port)

tcpclisock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpclisock.connect(addr)

def sendMSG():
    global msgscount, tcpclisock
    try:
        msgs.insert(msgscount, ">>" + msg.get())
        data = msg.get()
        msg.delete(0,END)
        msgscount += 1
        tcpclisock.send(data)
    except:
        easygui.msgbox(msg='You need to connect to a server.', title='Error')


def recvMSG():
    global msgscount,tcpclisock
    if setup == True:
        datar = tcpclisock.recv(buffsize)
        msgs.insert(msgscount, datar)
        msgscount += 1
        top.after(1000, recvMSG)
    else:
        answ = easygui.buttonbox(msg='Please join or create a server', title='Server', choices=("Create", 'Join'))
        if answ == "Create":
            makeServer()
        else:
            connectServer()


top = Tk()
top.geometry('640x650')

msgs = Listbox(top, width=105, height=43)
msgs.pack()

msg = Entry(top, bd=2, width=60, font='Arial 12 bold')
msg.pack(side=LEFT)

sendbtn = Button(top, text='Send', font='Arial 15 bold',width=15, padx=5, pady=5,command=runSendMSG)
sendbtn.pack(side=RIGHT)

menubar = Menu(top)
servermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
servermenu.add_command(label="Create Server", command=makeServer)
servermenu.add_command(label="Join Server", command=connectServer)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Server', menu=servermenu)

top.config(menu=menubar)

top.after(5000, recvMSG)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try to run this in terminal/cmd ? Did you get error message (trackback) ? I try to run it but: 1) in `sendbtn` you have `command=runSendMSG` but you don't have `runSendMSG()`. 2) use `global setup` in all function when you use `setup`. 3) error message `NameError: global name 'buffsize' is not defined`. etc.

Comment: I run code but Server and Client use `recv()` at the same time and both are wating for message so both are hanging. You probably need also `setblocking(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `easygui` so I removed some code

```
from Tkinter import *
#import easygui
import socket
#import threading

msgscount = 1

setup = False
buffsize = 1024

def makeServer():
    global tcpclisock,setup,buffsize
    host = ''
    port = 9000
    buffsize = 1024
    addr = (host, port)
    setup = True

    print "makeServer():"

    tcpsersock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsersock.bind(addr)
    tcpsersock.listen(5)
    tcpclisock, addr = tcpsersock.accept()
    tcpclisock.setblocking(0)
    print 'Connected from: ', addr
    top.after(1000, recvMSG)

def connectServer():
    global tcpclisock,setup,buffsize
    setup = True
    host = ''
    port = 9000
    buffsize = 1024
    addr = (host, port)

    tcpclisock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpclisock.connect(addr)
    print 'Connected to: ', addr
    tcpclisock.setblocking(0)
    top.after(1000, recvMSG)

def sendMSG():
    print 'sendMSG():'
    global msgscount, tcpclisock,setup
    try:
        msgs.insert(msgscount, ">>" + msg.get())
        data = msg.get()
        msg.delete(0,END)
        msgscount += 1
        print tcpclisock.send(data)
    except:
        print 'You need to connect to a server.'


def recvMSG():
    global msgscount,tcpclisock,setup,buffsize
    print 'recvMSG():', setup
    if setup == True:
        try:
            datar = tcpclisock.recv(buffsize)
            msgs.insert(msgscount, datar)
            msgscount += 1
        except:
            pass
        top.after(1000, recvMSG)
    else:
        pass
        answ = "Create"
        if answ == "Create":
            makeServer()
        else:
            connectServer()


top = Tk()
#top.geometry('640x650')

msgs = Listbox(top, width=105, height=43)
msgs.pack()

msg = Entry(top, bd=2, width=60, font='Arial 12 bold')
msg.pack()

sendbtn = Button(top, text='Send', font='Arial 15 bold', width=15, padx=5, pady=5, command=sendMSG)
sendbtn.pack()

menubar = Menu(top)
servermenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
servermenu.add_command(label="Create Server", command=makeServer)
servermenu.add_command(label="Join Server", command=connectServer)
menubar.add_cascade(label='Server', menu=servermenu)

top.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```